# Restart AIR MacOS Captive Runtime Bundle Application from code

Tags: macos, actionscript-3, air

Could anyone say how to restart it?

I found this sample and try to adapt it for me:

```
            var appLauncher:File;
                appLauncher = new File(File.applicationDirectory.nativePath).parent.parent.resolvePath("Contents").resolvePath("MacOS").resolvePath("FlashApp");

            var npInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo;
            npInfo.executable = appLauncher;
            var _args:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>;
            npInfo.arguments = _args;
            var np:NativeProcess = new NativeProcess;
            np.start(npInfo);
            np.exit();
```

But I don't understand how it should work.. Now nothing happends when this function called frome one of my classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try it with ADL? Or with actually packaged/installed app?

It is related its package structure.
If you try with ADL, it may not work.

Also,

- "FlashApp" must be changed to the name of your application,
- The last line should be `exit();` of your `NativeApplication`, not `np.exit()`

Comment: Right, I should use NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit() instead of np.exit(). Now it works correct, thanks.

Comment: Yeah I saw your post :'D Cheers!